# Regularization of fermionic field theory

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory, renormalization

My journey into fermionic field theory led me to [this very nice paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.01766.pdf) by M. Salmhofer, which gives an overview of such theories with applications to condensed matter theory. The path integral approach for such systems is written as:
$$Z = \operatorname{Tr}e^{-\beta (H - \mu N)} = \int d\bar{\phi}d\phi e^{-S(\bar{\phi},\phi)} \tag{1}\label{1}$$
where $S$ is the associated action of the model. As explained in the article, the right hand side of (\ref{1}) is usually just symbology: if one is considering continuous systems, the Grassmann variables $\bar{\phi}$ and $\phi$ are indexed by uncountable sets and the "measure" $d\bar{\phi}d\phi$ is ill-defined. One possible approach (I think the most used in the literature) is to consider a lattice space, where the operators $H$ and $N$ are naturally linear and bounded and $\operatorname{Tr}e^{-\beta (H - \mu N)}$ can be written as a limit by Trotter's formula. Hence, what *makes* sense is to write (\ref{1}) in a finite lattice and take the limits after the calculations are performed.

The point that is not clear to me is the following; as far as I know, turning a theory into a lattice model is important not only to make mathematical sense of objects not well-defined in infinite-dimensional spaces, but also to regularize the action $S$, which can be singular in the continuum case. When discussing the RG approach (section 3), however, Salmhofer considers an action (or, more precisely, the covariance $Q$ associated to its Gaussian measure) to be $\Omega$-dependent, where $\Omega$ is a given parameter in which $Q$ depends differentiably and such that $C_{\Omega} := Q_{\Omega}^{-1}$ exists. As discussed in the paper, $\Omega$ must also have a regularizing effect.

So, my question is: why do we need such parameter at all? I understand it is a very important piece in deriving the renormalization group equation, but I don't see why it is necessary once the theory is assumed to be discretized (thus, not singular). Are these two regularizations independent, i.e. do they serve different purposes? I am clearly missing the key idea of the regularization and RG equation, so it'd be very useful if someone addressed what the motivation and idea of this technique.

Comment: Haven't read the paper so this just a quick (possibly wrong) remark. Bottom of page 9 Manfred said $\Omega$ is an infrared cutoff. So it seems the lattice serves as a UV cutoff (eliminates large Fourier modes) while $\Omega$ is an IR cutoff (eliminates small Fourier modes).

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam if I understood your comment correctly, you mean that he might be using an infinite lattice and $\Omega$ garantees that the action in nonsingular?

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam I checked Manfred's book to see if I could get more insight on the problem. I skimmed the text and it seems to be considering a finite lattice. However, when he considers the fermi gas at chapter 4, he states that the covariance matrix is still singular in momentum space, even when the lattice is being used. I thought this would never happens, but it turns out I was mistaken. Apparently, this is what motivates the renormalizability. I'm mention all this to you just for completeness; I'm sure you already know all this.

Comment: Again I don't have time to look at this. But if say you are looking at the massless $(-\Delta)^{-1}$ on the lattice you have a singularity at momentum $\xi=0$. This is an infrared singularity, not a UV singularity. So it makes sense that putting an $\Omega$ regulates this singularity. "Apparently, this is what motivates the renormalizability" sounds to me like you are mixing some stuff up.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam I'm going to think more about this. But why did I sound like missing some stuff up (I actually think I'm missing some stuff up, but I don't know exactly what it).

Comment: "renormalizability" sounded like you were worrying about UV issues as in QFTs of high energy physics. It looks like Manfred's article is only about condensed matter physics, so there should not be any "renormalizability" issue, at least in the strict sense of the word.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam got it! Maybe this was the problem indeed; in any case, it was an important point you raised.